# Linear Gradient with border top

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

I am creating a tarpezoid shape using CSS. I want the color of trapezoid to slowly fade away. I created the trapezoid using the following CSS:

```
 $(".trapezoid-wrapper").css("border-top",'200px solid rgba('+finalRgb[0]+','+finalRgb[1]+','+finalRgb[2]+','+ 0.05 + ')');
 $(".trapezoid-wrapper").css("border-left", left + 'px solid transparent');
 $(".trapezoid-wrapper").css("border-right", left + 'px solid transparent');
```

Some static CSS on trapezoid wrapper:

```
.trapezoid-wrapper {
height: 495px; 
width: 535px;
bottom:-7px; 
position: absolute;
```

}

What I have got so far is: https://ibb.co/f83Pi7

I want the trapezoid color to slowly fade away as we move up. Can anyone please help on this? I tried with linear-gradient but its not working well.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know if any clarification is needed

Comment: Help us to help you :) Post a full working example of your existing code (including CSS, HTML and JS), so we can work from there.